# Ubuntu 18.04 splash screen hangs when shutting down on dual boot machine

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell inspiron-3542 machine alongside Windows 10, the installation seemed ok, but whenever I shutdown in Ubuntu the splash screen hangs. I always have to forcefully shutdown using the power button. I have tried `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to no avail. I have now received a message saying something like the root directory is full. When I use `df`it shows this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4004600       0   4004600   0% /dev
tmpfs             805492    1952    803540   1% /run
/dev/sda8       19154168 7828000  10330124  44% /
tmpfs            4027440   53032   3974408   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4027440       0   4027440   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1        189312  189312         0 100% /snap/eclipse/40
/dev/loop0        137472  137472         0 100% /snap/code/25
/dev/loop2        136704  136704         0 100% /snap/projectlibre/3
/dev/loop3         93568   93568         0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop4          4352    4352         0 100% /snap/tree/18
/dev/loop5          3840    3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop6         75904   75904         0 100% /snap/breaktimer/19
/dev/loop7         93568   93568         0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop8        164096  164096         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop9          4352    4352         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop10         1024    1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop11        46080   46080         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop12        15104   15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop13        56064   56064         0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/sda10      70607032 5089168  61888144   8% /home
/dev/sda1         507904   32548    475356   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs             805488      16    805472   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs             805488      40    805448   1% /run/user/1000
```

When I run `sudo du -sh /* | sort -rh`, the output is:

```
du: cannot access '/proc/3142/task/3142/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3142/task/3142/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3142/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/3142/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
4.9G    /home
4.2G    /usr
3.2G    /snap
2.6G    /var
622M    /lib
91M /boot
14M /etc
13M /bin
12M /sbin
2.0M    /run
124K    /tmp
88K /root
16K /lost+found
8.0K    /media
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /opt
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /cdrom
0   /vmlinuz.old
0   /vmlinuz
0   /sys
0   /proc
0   /initrd.img.old
0   /initrd.img
0   /dev
```

I have also tried running Ubuntu in recovery mode and attempted to perform `fsck` but it says `/dev/sda8` is mounted. I tried `umount /dev/sda8` but it says it is still active. I could unmount the /dev/sda8 but I am new to Linux and don't want to screw up my laptop. Please could you advise me on what to do.

**Update - display usage information of an Intel GPU**

```
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 1, Operation not permitted
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
Stack trace:
  #0 [_init+0x7b87]
  #1 [_init+0x5420]
  #2 [_init+0xe85]
  #3 [__libc_start_main+0xe7]
  #4 [_init+0x1c92]
Test (null) failed.
**** DEBUG ****
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-chipset-DEBUG: Test requirement passed: pci_dev
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Test assertion failure function intel_mmio_use_pci_bar, file ../../lib/intel_mmio.c:145:
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Failed assertion: !(error != 0)
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Last errno: 1, Operation not permitted
(intel_gpu_top:5781) intel-mmio-CRITICAL: Couldn't map MMIO region
(intel_gpu_top:5781) igt-core-INFO: Stack trace:
(intel_gpu_top:5781) igt-core-INFO:   #0 [_init+0x7b87]
(intel_gpu_top:5781) igt-core-INFO:   #1 [_init+0x5420]
(intel_gpu_top:5781) igt-core-INFO:   #2 [_init+0xe85]
(intel_gpu_top:5781) igt-core-INFO:   #3 [__libc_start_main+0xe7]
(intel_gpu_top:5781) igt-core-INFO:   #4 [_init+0x1c92]
****  END  ****
FAIL (-1.000s)
```

What has it failed and how should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSb and then you can run fsck on your internal drive(s).

Comment: @K7AAY I ran fsck using a live USB and it says all the Linux partitions are clean except from `/dev/sda1` which gave the output: `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:00/01
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action
? 3` I chose no action. Should I have selected one of the other options?

Comment: @K7AAY I selected 2) and now the splash screen stops hanging, thanks for your help. However when I view the Disk Usage Analyzer, the root directory is red and full. I can see lost+found is also red and when I view and sort the root sub-directories by size, lost+found is the largest folder with 16K, however cd lost+found displays only `.  ..`. How can I view the 16K contents of lost+found?

Comment: @K7AAY Oh so are you suggesting that I delete /dev/sda8? Isn't that a bit radical? I am not to bothered about retrieve lost+found contents - I just want to free some space because `df` is showing that I have 66% free space on /dev/sda8.

Comment: @K7AAY I deleted the partitions and reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 as you suggested but the splash screen hanging has returned. I installed intel-gpu-tools and ran `sudo intel_gpu_top` and it displayed errors described in my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my BIOS and it appears to have resolved the splash screen hanging issue. However, my Disk Usage Analyzer is still reporting the root as full with a red bar, and that some of the folders in root could not be scanned. I know my partition is nowhere near saturation because I extended the volume and `df` is showing that it's like 1% used.